# how to remove Yiddish scoring from a string in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

I get characters from a API URL request like this ִֵנׂקֹוַדֹּוֶת and I went to get only the text.
How can I convert it in PHP AND in javascript?

```
from נׂקֹוַדֹּוֶת
to נקודות
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in PHP you can use this

```
$str = 'נׂקֹוַדֹּוֶת ';
$rule = 'NFD; [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; NFC';

$myTrans = Transliterator::create($rule); 
echo $myTrans->transliterate($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

FOR JavaScript you can use this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>JavaScript can change נקודות content.</p>

<p id="demo">JavaScript can change נקודות content.</p>

<script>
var string = "נׂקֹוַדֹּוֶת";

var string_norm = string.replace(/[ְֱֲֳִֵֶַָֹֹּׁׂ]/g, '');
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (string_norm);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider including a brief explanation of [how and why this solves the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/13138364). This will help readers to better understand your solution.